# Gaussian process regression (Kriging) vs Radial Basis Function interpolation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, interpolation

I've implemented 2 types of interpolation for temperature data between sensors over a floorplan. Since I'm not very well-versed in the underlying processes and maths of the packages I used, I'm finding it hard to understand why their outputs through pcolormesh are so different.

I used `scipy.interpolate.Rbf` and `sklearn.gaussian_process`.

These are the images.

[Gaussian process regression](https://ibb.co/CM9pBLw)

[Radial Basis Function interpolation](https://ibb.co/zNpYBfg)

The RBF example looks exactly like implementations found around the web yet the GPR one displays these long lines instead of circular shapes. What parameter would regulate these shapes in Scikit learn's implementation of GPR? Why are they so different in shape and sometimes intensity of colour when temperature results for GPR change even slightly.

The 9 sensors (dots) over the floorplan are distributed uniformly.

Code for RBF.

```
# Set X and Y Coordinates for each sensor (pixels)
    days_data['xCoordinate'] = days_data.nodeid.apply(lambda id: createXCoord(id))
    days_data['yCoordinate'] = days_data.nodeid.apply(lambda id: createYCoord(id))

    # Define location of "sensors" on the axes
    x = days_data.xCoordinate.to_list()
    y = days_data.yCoordinate.to_list()
    z = days_data.avgtemperature.to_list() #temperature

    # Use Gaussian function
    rbf_adj = Rbf(x, y, z, function = 'gaussian')

    # Set extent to which colour mesh stretches over
    # the underlying image
    x_fine = np.linspace(0, 1000, 81) #81 - num of samples
    y_fine = np.linspace(0, 700, 81)

    x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_fine, y_fine)

    z_grid = rbf_adj(x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()).reshape(x_grid.shape)

    # Remove the colorbar created by the previous plot, if any
    # To avoid a new colorbar being plotted alongside the previous one each time a different date is selected
    try:
        cb = p.colorbar
        cb.remove()
    except:
        pass

    # plot the pcolor on the Axes. Use alpha to set the transparency
    p=ax.pcolor(x_fine, y_fine, z_grid, alpha=0.3)
    ax.invert_yaxis() #invert Y axis for X and Y to have same starting point

    # Add a colorbar for the pcolor field
    fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax)
```

Code for GPR

```
 # Define location of "sensors" on the axes
    x = days_data.xCoordinate.to_list()
    y = days_data.yCoordinate.to_list()
    z = days_data.avgtemperature.to_list() #temperature

    X = np.array([[a, b] for a, b in zip(x, y)])

    # Set extent to which colour mesh stretches over
    # the underlying image
    x_fine = np.linspace(0, 1000, 81) #81 - num of samples
    y_fine = np.linspace(0, 700, 82)
    X_fine = np.array([[a_fine, b_fine] for a_fine, b_fine in zip(x_fine, y_fine)])

    x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_fine, y_fine)

    # Instantiate a Gaussian Process model
    kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(10, (1e-2, 1e2))
    gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=9)

    # Fit to data using Maximum Likelihood Estimation of the parameters
    gp.fit(X, z)
    z_grid, sigma = gp.predict(X_fine, return_std=True)

    # Remove the colorbar created by the previous plot, if any
    # To avoid a new colorbar being plotted alongside the previous one each time a different date is selected
    try:
        cb = p.colorbar
        cb.remove()
    except:
        pass

    # plot the pcolor on the Axes. Use alpha to set the transparency
    p = ax.pcolor(x_grid, y_grid, np.meshgrid(z_grid, y_fine)[0], alpha=0.3)
    ax.invert_yaxis() #invert Y axis for X and Y to have same starting point

    # Add a colorbar for the pcolor field
    fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax)
```

Comment: In the GPR code, why did you use `np.meshgrid(z_grid, y_fine)[0]` as the third argument to `pcolor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the scale parameters of the gaussian process are very different in the x and y directions, with a small x scale parameter and a relatively larger y scale parameter. This way, two points with a small x distance have low correlation and two points with a small y distance have a high correlation: this creates vertical "bands" in the temperature profile.

I was able to simulate this with the following data, with [OpenTURNS](http://www.openturns.org/). You did not provide the temperatures, so I had to guess them from the graphics.

```
import numpy as np
import openturns as ot
coordinates = ot.Sample([[100.0,100.0],[500.0,100.0],[900.0,100.0], \
                         [100.0,350.0],[500.0,350.0],[900.0,350.0], \
                         [100.0,600.0],[500.0,600.0],[900.0,600.0]])
observations = ot.Sample([25.0,25.0,10.0,20.0,25.0,20.0,15.0,25.0,25.0],1)

# Extract coordinates
x = np.array(coordinates[:,0])
y = np.array(coordinates[:,1])

# Plot the data with a scatter plot and a color map
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, c=observations, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This produces:

[image: Observed temperatures]

Fitting a kriging metamodel from this can be done with the following script. I used a squared exponential covariance model.

```
def fitKriging(coordinates, observations, covarianceModel, basis):
    '''
    Fit the parameters of a kriging metamodel. 
    '''
    algo = ot.KrigingAlgorithm(coordinates, observations, covarianceModel, basis)
    algo.run()
    krigingResult = algo.getResult()
    krigingMetamodel = krigingResult.getMetaModel()
    return krigingResult, krigingMetamodel

inputDimension = 2
basis = ot.ConstantBasisFactory(inputDimension).build()
covarianceModel = ot.SquaredExponential([1.]*inputDimension, [1.0])
krigingResult, krigingMetamodel = fitKriging(coordinates, observations, covarianceModel, basis)
```

To plot the predictions from this kriging metamodel, I used the following script, based on the `pcolor` function.

```
def plotKrigingPredictions(krigingMetamodel):
    '''
    Plot the predictions of a kriging metamodel. 
    '''
    # Create the mesh of the box [0., 1000.] * [0., 700.]
    myInterval = ot.Interval([0., 0.], [1000., 700.])
    # Define the number of interval in each direction of the box
    nx = 20
    ny = 20
    myIndices = [nx-1, ny-1]
    myMesher = ot.IntervalMesher(myIndices)
    myMeshBox = myMesher.build(myInterval)

    # Predict
    vertices = myMeshBox.getVertices()
    predictions = krigingMetamodel(vertices)

    # Format for plot
    X = np.array(vertices[:,0]).reshape((ny,nx))
    Y = np.array(vertices[:,1]).reshape((ny,nx))
    predictions_array = np.array(predictions).reshape((ny,nx))

    # Plot
    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolor(X, Y, predictions_array)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
    return

plotKrigingPredictions(krigingMetamodel)
```

This produces:

[image: Temperatures with different scales]

You can see the same bands as in your predictions.

Looking at the covariance model explains why:

```
>>> covarianceModel = krigingResult.getCovarianceModel()
>>> print(covarianceModel)
SquaredExponential(scale=[0.167256,1.5929], amplitude=[6.75753])
```

The x-scale is 0.1672, which is much small than the y-scale 1.593. This is because we used an anisotropic covariance model, where the x-scale theta can be different from the y-scale theta.

In order to fix this, we could use an isotropic covariance model, where the x-scale is maintained equal to the y-scale. However, it is simpler just to set the x and y scales at a given value, and to estimate the amplitude parameter sigma only.

The following script set the scales to the mean of the previous estimate and estimates sigma only.

```
scales = covarianceModel.getScale()
meanScale = (scales[0]+scales[1])/2.0
covarianceModel.setScale([meanScale]*2)
covarianceModel.setActiveParameter([2]) # Enable sigma (amplitude) only
# Learn amplitude only
krigingResult, krigingMetamodel = fitKriging(coordinates, observations, covarianceModel, basis)
covarianceModel = krigingResult.getCovarianceModel()
print("Covariance model=",covarianceModel)
```

This prints:

```
Covariance model= SquaredExponential(scale=[0.880079,0.880079], amplitude=[6.1472])
```

Finally, the following script:

```
plotKrigingPredictions(krigingMetamodel)
```

plots:

[image: Temperatures with same scales]

Since the theta parameter is the same in both directions, the temperature is now spherical, as I guess you would expect it should be.